# Writing a screenplay versus a short story

Tags: short-story, screenwriting

I've been writing short stories throughout my life, in a humorous style. Yet, these stories lack a literary quality, and the prose is rather plain. I'm debating whether to start writing screenplays instead, where there is a minimal amount of description.

Is there even a point to writing in a play/screenplay style, knowing that very few people would care to read it? What can be done with a screenplay?

Is it perhaps more sensible to try and work on my style and expression, so that the ultimate format would be a short story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "literary quality." It sounds like you are saying that you don't use a lot of description. Writing a screenplay to avoid writing description is cheating yourself out of the opportunity to make yourself a better writer.

I would suggest instead that you keep going with short stories but, before each scene, sit down and describe the setting in detail to yourself. Think about it visually, but also what sounds do you hear? What do you smell? Is your character visiting their grandmother? Does the house always smell vaguely like the pot roast she makes for Sunday dinner? Does her favorite chair have a cushion that is squashed flat from being sat on for years? Does she have lots of pictures on the wall? Is one the center of attention? Is that annoying cousin missing from the photos? Does her parakeet talk all the time? You don't need to put all of this in your story, but some of it would be good. Setting can be used to flesh out characters.